# Python Syntax error on colon in List

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a time series plot, and I have data points every second for about 50 seconds of time (which in my case is in UTC). Python is yelling at me about my array of data in the x axis of my plot, which is as follows:

```
%run "C:/Users/Jeff/Desktop/Python/STEPS_data.py"
File "C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Python\STEPS_data.py", line 3   
x = [23:13:51,23:13:52,23:13:53,23:13:54,23:13:55,23:13:56,23:13:57,23:13:58,23:13:59,23:14:00,23:14:01,23:14:02,23:14:03,23:14:04,23:14:05,23:14:06,23:14:07,23:14:08,23:14:09,23:14:10,23:14:11,23:14:12,23:14:13,23:14:14,23:14:15,23:14:16,23:14:17,23:14:18,23:14:19,23:14:20,23:14:21,23:14:22,23:14:23,23:14:24,23:14:25,23:14:26,23:14:27,23:14:28,23:14:29,23:14:30,23:14:31,23:14:32,23:14:33,23:14:34,23:14:35,23:14:36]
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There's a bunch of other info about the plot after this, but it gets hung up on this line, where it says that I have an invalid syntax error at the first colon in the array element `23:14:23`, which doesn't really make sense to me. I tried making the array its own variable `x1` and just saying `x = x1`, but that only pushed the syntax error point back by one character.

This seems like a really stupid problem but I'm stumped.

Comment: `:` isn't allowed there. Did you forget to wrap them in `""` (i.e. `"23:13:51"`) to mark them as strings?

Comment: OK, so I have to put each element of the array in quotation marks if I have a colon in the element?

Comment: Do you want to convert the elements of the list to datetime objects?

Comment: "colon in element -> use quotation marks" is cargo cult programming, and you would be much better served by learning about the different types and their literal representations.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 woot? Didn't get you.

Comment: @MYGz - I mean that the OP doesn't seem to understand _why_ this is a syntax error, and what the difference is when each element is wrapped in quotes. It's just being seen as something that makes the code magically not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `:` is not allowed everywhere, for example:

```
>>> a = 10:2
  File "<ipython-input-12-63c21fb7e990>", line 1
    a = 10:2
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think you wanted them as strings (in strings the `:` are allowed):

```
l = ['23:13:51', '23:13:52', '23:13:53', '23:13:54', '23:13:55', '23:13:56',
     '23:13:57', '23:13:58', '23:13:59', '23:14:00', '23:14:01', '23:14:02', '23:14:03',
     '23:14:04', '23:14:05', '23:14:06', '23:14:07', '23:14:08', '23:14:09', '23:14:10',
     '23:14:11', '23:14:12', '23:14:13', '23:14:14', '23:14:15', '23:14:16', '23:14:17',
     '23:14:18', '23:14:19', '23:14:20', '23:14:21', '23:14:22', '23:14:23', '23:14:24',
     '23:14:25', '23:14:26', '23:14:27', '23:14:28', '23:14:29', '23:14:30', '23:14:31',
     '23:14:32', '23:14:33', '23:14:34', '23:14:35', '23:14:36']
```

In case you don't want to add all these `''` manually just wrap the whole thing as a string and split it:

```
>>> l = "[23:13:51,23:13:52,23:13:53,23:13:54,23:13:55,23:13:56,23:13:57,23:13:58,23:13:59,23:14:00,23:14:01,23:14:02,23:14:03,23:14:04,23:14:05,23:14:06,23:14:07,23:14:08,23:14:09,23:14:10,23:14:11,23:14:12,23:14:13,23:14:14,23:14:15,23:14:16,23:14:17,23:14:18,23:14:19,23:14:20,23:14:21,23:14:22,23:14:23,23:14:24,23:14:25,23:14:26,23:14:27,23:14:28,23:14:29,23:14:30,23:14:31,23:14:32,23:14:33,23:14:34,23:14:35,23:14:36]"
>>> l[1:-1].split(',')
```

or did you want them as `datetime`s?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> [datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M:%S') for t in l[1:-1].split(',')]
```

or `time`s?

```
>>> [datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M:%S').time() for t in l[1:-1].split(',')]
```

Comment: @jwetter10 But you didn't tell which part of the answer solved your problem? :D